# how i will use this jquery variable in php

Tags: codeigniter

i will get two jquery value in jquery variable how i will convert value in php variable

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".slv").change(function()
            {
            var proid = $(this).attr('id');
            var proval = $(this).val();
            <?php $id1=?>proid;
          <?php $id2=?>proval;
        <?php
              $data = array('name' => $id1,
                'value'=>$id2, 
                'expire'=>'86500');

        $this->input->set_cookie($data);
        ?>

            });

    });
```

Comment: hello pleace help me

Comment: client-side script !== server-side script .... you can't just go from jquery/js to php like that... you need ajax or something like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0):

Try set value into a cookie.

Here you will see how you can do it

[how to assign javascript variable value to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620133/how-to-assign-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax to post these values

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/test/testcontroller/testfunction",
        data: {'proid':proid,'proval':proval},
        success: function(data)
            {
            },

```
    }
```

});

And in controller you  can get it like

$this->input->post('proid');
$this->input->post('proval');