# How to Convert jQuery ajax success data to a PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending data to a `php` page for processing through `jQuery` and `ajax` and as result I will get

```
success: function(data){
mydata = data;
}
```

my data is an url that looks like `mydata = https://myurl.com`. Now I want to set mydata to a `php` variable and use it again inside another function in the main page, means: to set `$url = mydata;`.
How can I do that?

Thanks,

Comment: You can't set a PHP variables from JS on the same page. PHP is executed on the server, then the result of that gets sent to the client where the JS gets executed. If you want to pass the JS variable through a PHP function, you need to do a new Ajax call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PHP scripts execute when you open a file and before everything else.
Ajax calls exectue when the Javascript is completely loaded. (After php).

So you cant do it.
could you give me more detail about what do you want to do?

Comment: Is it possible to set `$url` to the result of output  `<div id="result"></div>` that can be shown after adding this below code to `success: function(data)` and the code is:  `$('#result').html(data)` ?

Comment: Actually No. PHP is executed on the server. JS is executed on the client computer and they cant communicate with each other without someting like Ajax Call or Fetch or ... .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Post via a from, GET via a query string
or you can use cookie like in this solution

[how to assign javascript variable value to php variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620133/how-to-assign-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable)

Comment: Reading the question, it looks like the OP wants to set a PHP variable on the same page after an Ajax request, not in another script (POST or GET) or after a page reload (Cookies).

Comment: If that's the case he can use another ajax request to trigger the function that will set the variable.

Comment: No, the OP wants to store the response from an ajax request in a PHP variable _on the same page_. That simply can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `mydata` variable to `PHP` by calling an `XMLHttpRequest()` via `AJAX`.
**For example**

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Create new request
ajax.open("POST", "mainpage.php"); // Open the file where you want to send it with POST
ajax.send("mydata="+mydata); // Send mydata variable to PHP
```

Then in `PHP` you can check for the variable `mydata`

```
if(isset($_POST['mydata'])){
    // do something
}
```