# PHP variable can be assign to javascript variable but javascript variable can't assign to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

If we have a variable in php which holds a value then we can assign easily this value to js variable but the vice versa is possible?

For Assign php variable to js variable we use

```
 <?php $r = 1; ?>
 <script>
  var s = "<?php echo $r; ?>";
 </script>
```

But for assign js variable to php variable its not works

```
 <script>
  var s = 1;
 </script>
 <?php $r = echo "<script> s </script>"; ?>'
```

Not working

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620133/how-to-assign-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable

Comment: save the value in localStorage using javascript, and fetch it using php.

Comment: probably duplicate

Comment: The easiest way to do this is with AJAX, though it can also be done with a cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, PHP is server side while Javascript is client side. You can do it by creating a browser cookie using Javascript and then use PHP to read that cookie.

Anyway, why do you want to do that?