# Set Javascript variable as PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

Hai I want to set javascript variable (getdate1) as PHP variable to compare the dates with database value to display event details. I attached the attachement of how alert box will work.

```
        var getdate1 = document.getElementById("eventDayName").innerHTML = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            year: "numeric"
        }); 

        alert(getdate1);
```

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620133/how-to-assign-javascript-variable-value-to-php-variable

Answer (score 0):

HTML: 
    `<input type='hidden' id='myDate' name='myDate'>`
JS: 
    `document.getElementById('myDate').value = getDate1;`
PHP: 
    `$date = $_POST['myDate'];`

Explanation:  Make a hidden html element. Set its value with javascript.  Get its value with PHP.

Comment: If you go to the console and view the value of the HTML element (document.getElementById('myDate').value), is it displaying?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: getDate1 is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.gridTable.onclick (calender.php:745)
gridTable.onclick @ calender.php:745

Comment: Try assigning the date to getDate1 and the dom element separately, like this:  var getDate1 = selectedDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            year: "numeric"
        });               document.getElementById("eventDayName").innerHTML = getDate1;